# Find The Rank of The User Test MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is MySQL Query which Currently Fetching The All User Ranking. but i want to Fetch particular user rank.

```
SELECT Percentage_of_Marks,mark,test_id,
       1+(SELECT count(*) from user_test a
          WHERE a.Percentage_of_Marks > b.Percentage_of_Marks) as RNK,
       Percentage_of_Marks
FROM user_test b
ORDER BY b.Percentage_of_Marks DESC
```

my Query Result is.

[image]

how to find the RNK of the particular test_id.

Comment: add where test_id = 't-044'  ( after the from clause and before order by)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Percentage_of_Marks,mark,test_id, 
    1+
    (
        SELECT count(*) 
        from user_test a 
        WHERE a.Percentage_of_Marks > b.Percentage_of_Marks
    ) as RNK, 
    Percentage_of_Marks 
FROM user_test b 
where b.test_id='$test_id'  
ORDER BY b.Percentage_of_Marks DESC limit 1
```